# Flatten an array based on the count of subchild

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the solution for the problem but is their any better approach to do this

```js
var arr1 = [
    {
        name: 'Ajinkya',
        job: 'Engineer 3',
        tasks: ['task1', 'task2', 'task3']
    },
    {
        name: 'Vidhya',
        job: 'Engineer 1',
        tasks: ['task1', 'task2']
    },
    {
        name: 'Saravana',
        job: 'Engineer 2',
        tasks: ['task2', 'task3']
    },
]

var arr2=[];

arr1.map(e1=>{
    e1['tasks'].forEach(e2=>{
        arr2.push({ name: e1["name"], job: e1["name"], tasks: e2  })
    })
})
console.log(arr2);
```

Just wanted to iterate the array like the above output, even have a solution, but just wondering about a better approach.

Comment: Is  `job: e1["name"]` supposed to be  `job: e1["job"]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flatMap()` and use `map()` over the `tasks` for each object

```js
var arr1 = [
    {
        name: 'Ajinkya',
        job: 'Engineer 3',
        tasks: ['task1', 'task2', 'task3']
    },
    {
        name: 'Vidhya',
        job: 'Engineer 1',
        tasks: ['task1', 'task2']
    },
    {
        name: 'Saravana',
        job: 'Engineer 2',
        tasks: ['task2', 'task3']
    },
]

const res = arr1.flatMap(x => x.tasks.map(tasks => ({...x, tasks})));
console.log(res)
```